# why isn't my radio button getting selected?

Tags: jquery, html

jquery:

This is my edited jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#set-button").click(function(){
        $("#radio-choice-a").attr("checked", "checked");
        counter=aRoute;
        $('#data-scroller').scroller('destroy');
        scroller();     
    });
});
```

html: edited

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-a"
              value="on" checked="checked" /> <label for="radio-choice-a">A</label>
               <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-b"
               value="off" /> <label for="radio-choice-b">B</label> 
               <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-c"
           value="other" /> <label for="radio-choice-c">C</label>
       </fieldset>
</div>
<a href="#" id="set-button" data-theme="a">Set</a>
```

Does any one know how it can be done?

Comment: The first two don't DO anything, they simply select. As to the last two - why don't you simply select using `$('#radio-choice-a')`? If you do, `$('#radio-choice-a').attr('checked', 'checked');` should work.

Comment: Considering you have `checked="checked"` explicitly in the HTML, I don't see why you would *need* javascript for this. Should be already selected.

Comment: Have you insert the javascript in head or at body? Some people try to access the element before the elements be rendered, so you need to use ready `$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`

Comment: javascript is at head portion of the html.

Comment: Are you using an JQuery UI buttonset on the fieldset?  Is it possible that the checkbox is getting update, but the UI is not refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I used this and it worked. The reason it did not work earlier was because i was using jquery.mobile-1.1.1 javascript file. So it needs to be refreshed to update the visual styling.

```
 $("#radio-choice-a").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9y5na/

You might as well just search by that ID if that's the specific one you want. Use `.prop('checked', true);` and you're all set. Also radio-choice-a already has checked="checked" within it, why it might seem like the JS isn't doing anything!

```
$("#radio-choice-a").prop("checked", true);​
```

Comment: If you look at the demo it starts out automatically selected

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$("#radio-choice-a").attr("checked", "checked");​
$("#buttonSetSelector").buttonset("refresh");    //If you are using a buttonset

$("#radio-choice-a").button("refresh");   // If you are just using buttons
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/SLqWG/4/

Comment: Where are you running the javascript?  If you open chrome development tools, do you see any errors?

Comment: i have edited my html. can you show me how to refresh on that?

Comment: Can you post the jquery UI button calls?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15355/discussion-between-codebeginner-and-john-koerner)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the elements by their IDs, also you can use the `prop` method for modifying the `checked` property of the inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radio-choice-a').prop('checked', true)
    $('#radio-choice-b').prop('checked', false)
})
```

Comment: @codebeginner Do you put the scripts inside the `$(document).ready` handler?

Comment: i have a button which when clicked should reset the value to A. So i placed it under the click function

Comment: an array and some function that I am calling. Everything is working in the click function except checking the radio button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15352/discussion-between-codebeginner-and-undefined)

Comment: @codebeginner Yes, have you alerted something inside the click handler?

Comment: @codebeginner So please alert something for check to see that handler is called.

Comment: it is called, other statements under it were executed perfectly except for that one statement.

Comment: @codebeginner This is weird, surely the selector doesn't select the element, check your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('radio-choice-a')​​​​.checked=true;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)